# Zooming in UIScrollview Programmatically Does Not Work

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm using double tap to zoom in an imageView inside a scrollview.

The method below works fine (imageView zooms in/out) when it's called from button tap action.

However I need to call the method programmatically to zoom in, when I do, nothing happens: imageView is not zooming in.

What am I missing?

Below is the exact copy of `@objc func doubleTapped()` method I'm using with tap location replaced with arbitrary CGPoint

```swift
func doubleTappedCustom() {

        var scale: CGFloat = 2

        let ratioW = imageView.frame.width / imageView.image!.size.width
        let ratioH = imageView.frame.height / imageView.image!.size.height

        let ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW:ratioH

        let newWidth = imageView.image!.size.width * ratio
        let newHeight = imageView.image!.size.height * ratio


        if (imageView.image.size.width < imageView.size.height){
            if scale > imageView.frame.width / newWidth {
                scale = imageView.frame.width / newWidth
            }
        }


        let location = CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.width/2, y: imageView.frame.height/2)

        if scrollView.zoomScale == 1 {
            // here tap location is repalced with 'location' cgpoint
            scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale, center: location), animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
{
    return image
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20

}
```

Comment: I already have both viewForZooming and scrollview delegate, min, max zoom scale setup. Again, double tap zoom in/out works fine when called from button tap action. The double tap method described in my question above does not work when called programmatically (without button tap action)

Comment: Show the UITapGestureRecognizer code, you have both single and double tap in use and they're both set to the correct numberOfTapsRequired = ?

Comment: Sorry, may be I wasn't clear before. When I use the code in my question with UITapGestureRecognizer, it works fine. It's not what I'm asking. The problem I'm facing is that I need to call the above code not with double tap gesture, but from another method. Basically, once my imageView and imageScrollView are setup and initialized I call this zoom in method (doubleTappedCustom) which works if called from button tap, and which does not work when called from somewhere else. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was resolved by moving zooming code to `viewDidAppear`